# How does JavaScript represent DateTime values internally?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a program that uses JavaScript for scripting.  Like most script systems, there's a predefined library of native functions that scripts can call into, and I just added a new one.

The new function takes a DateTime (it's in Delphi, where a DateTime is represented internally by a Double), a string and a boolean.  The last two parameters come through just fine, but it appears that somewhere in the system, the time value is getting mangled.  Instead of a recognizable DateTime, I get `1362394800000`, which doesn't make any sense according to Delphi's timestamp scheme.

Where can I find information on how JavaScript represents DateTime values, so I can figure out how to translate this into something my Delphi code can use?  (This is using Microsoft's JScript system that comes standard with Windows 7, in case the implementation varies.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript represents Date objects as a number of *milliseconds* since the Epoch. This is important, because most other systems and languages use just integer seconds.

So assuming Delphi is one such second user, you should be able to divide the number by 1000 and pass it in.

Comment: Delphi isn't a one-second user.  It uses the integer part of the double as *days* since the Epoch (I think) and the fractional part to represent hours, minutes, seconds, etc.  But knowing this, I can get it to convert.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's stored as a number of milliseconds since 1/1/1970 00:00:00.000

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) values are internally represented as milliseconds since [unix epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time); that's the value you get by using `.getTime()` are casting the object to a number.